# TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing :

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_name")
public class Test extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ALL_ORG_MST_SECTION_ID",nullable = true)
    private AllOrgMst allOrgMstSection;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn(name = "ALL_ORG_MST_SUB_SECTION_ID",nullable = true)
    private AllOrgMst allOrgMstSubSection;


    
}
```

This is the model . when I insert this model one object is null value then show
me the error

Post man Object pass

```
{
   "allOrgMstSection": {
        "id": 23
    },
    "allOrgMstSubSection": {
        "id": null
    }
}
```

```
  @Autowired
    private TestRepository testRepository;

    @Override
    public Test save2(Test entity) {
        return testRepository.save(entity);
    }
```

In baseEntity have the Id

Comment: Please add the code fragment from the service / controller from where you are invoking the save call into the `TestRepository`

Comment: @RatulSharker
added

Comment: @RatulSharker
Yes I solved the problem just Adding 
{
allOrgMstSubSection:null
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just simply soled the issue

```
{
   "allOrgMstSection": {
        "id": 23
    },
    "allOrgMstSubSection": null,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the log you provided and the model, its clear that you are trying to save an non-managed object, which have `id`.

The solution is to before saving, make the transient object managed (Which are already in the db).

Here the

```json
"allOrgMstSection": {
        "id": 23
    },
```

portion seems to already present in the database. Grabbing the managed object / proxy object will solve the issue.

The `service` layer code should be similar to following

```java
public Test save(Test test) {
    if(test.getAllOrgMstSection() != null && test.getAllOrgMstSection().getId() != null) {
        Long id = test.getAllOrgMstSection().getId();        
        test.setAllOrgMstSection(allOrgMstSectionRepository.getOne(id));
    }

    if(test.getAllOrgMstSubSection() != null && test.getAllOrgMstSubSection().getId() != null ) {
        Long id = test.getAllOrgMstSubSection().getId();
        test.setAllOrgMstSubSection(allOrgMstSubSectionRepository.getOne(id));
    }
    return testRepository.save(test);
}
```

Basically what is done, managed the child object (if they are already present in the database) before saving the parent object. If it does not present in the database.

If you need to perform any update on the child object (i.e updating `allOrgMstSection` while saving the `test` entity) you have to manually copy the properties. In that case, you could use [`BeanUtils.copyProperties()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-)

The code should be similar to following

```
if(test.getAllOrgMstSection() != null && test.getAllOrgMstSection().getId() != null) {
     AllOrgMstSection updatedAllOrgMsgSection = test.getAllOrgMstSection();

     Long id = test.getAllOrgMstSection().getId();
     AllOrgMstSection existingAllOrgMstSection = allOrgMstSectionRepository.findById(id);
     
     BeanUtils.copyProperties(updatedAllOrgMsgSection, existingAllOrgMstSection /*pass property names you don't want to update*/);
     test.setAllOrgMstSection(existingAllOrgMstSection);
}
```

Comment: hi @bulbul does this answer solved your issue ?